# Dealing with imbalanced data set and cross-validation

Tags: matlab, dataset, classification, cross-validation, pattern-recognition

I have a data set of brain tumours, 700 malignant, and 225 benign. And I want to build a classification model using SVM, to classify the tumours types based on the data I have.
My first question, is it considered an imbalanced dataset? if so, should I do undersampling of the malignant class?

Also, is it correct to use the below code to do cross-validation for my dataset?
NOTE: groups = instances' labels vector (sorted malignant 0s then benign 1s)
      data = instances' data feature matrix

```
k=10;
cp = classperf(groups); 
cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', groups, k);   
 for i = 1:k                                 
  testIdx = (cvFolds == i);                %# get indices of test instances
  trainIdx = ~testIdx;                     %# get indices training instances


   svmModel = fitcsvm(data(trainIdx,:), groups(trainIdx), 
   'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','RBF','KernelScale','auto');

  pred = predict(svmModel, meas(testIdx,:));
  cp = classperf(cp, pred, testIdx);
end
```

I still couldn't understand how `crossvalind` works? I mean does it guarantee that it takes instances from both classes at each fold?

Comment: No, keep all the data, your SVM is simply going to create the best possible separation (a line, an hyperplan,...) between the two categories. On top of that, SVM only consider the support vectors to create this separation.

Comment: Thank you, sir! what if I try the KNN (K nearest neighbour) classifier, is it the same case or should the dataset or the cross-validation method be modified?

Comment: In this case it could be a little bit more problematic. Take [this example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Iris_dataset_scatterplot.svg/400px-Iris_dataset_scatterplot.svg.png): If your two dataset are well separated by your N parameter it won't be a problem (blue vs red) but if they are not (blue vs green) some outliers in the "malignant" dataset could lead to a bad classification (there could be a lot of malignant outlier close to the begnin data). So in this case it could be interesting to undersample the malignant dataset, you need to chose according to your data.